# JPA Cache working with nginx

Tags: spring, jpa, caching, nginx

I have many instances of the same Spring application, that are working on different ports. I have also nginx server, which is a loadbalancer - it handles a request and pass it to one instance, which handles it. These apps work with DB in order to store and transfer some data. What about JPA Cache in this situation? If I am thinking good, every single instance has its own cache - is there a way to share a cache between these instances? Or maybe a better idea would be turning off JPA Cache, and using some cache above the apps?

Comment: which "JPA Cache" ? Level 1 (EntityManager) ?, Level 2 (EntityManagerFactory) ?, query cache ?

Comment: The first level cache is per server as that is the `Entitymanager`, the second level cache depends on the cache you are using and how that is setup.

Comment: I meant level 2. I've read that eg. Hazelcast would be a good choice? Am I right?